# flash media server: can i record video/audio from a running swf?

Tags: flash-media-server

i have flash media server installed and i wrote some flash games using action script 3.

is there a way for me to allow the users to record their plays so they'll be able to watch it later from my fms server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within the game you could approximate their actions but I don't believe that you can actually make a video of all the frames. I know there are apps out there that do that but they don't run within the swf.

But if you really wanted to you could just put a blanket click listener on the stage, record the position of the mouse and the time that it was clicked and any other state that would be necessary. As long as there's no randomness in the game this would work for a replay. If there is randomness you'll have to store the random number generator seed as well so that you can make sure that the randomness is the same each time.

I hope that helps direct you down some useful paths.